# Does being an independent contractor count as a mini-job?

Tags: germany, taxes, employment

I have a work permit and a full time job in Germany.
I now want to have a mini-job on the side (450€/month).

I received a contract from another company, working ~5h/week, which does not exceed 450€ per month. However, the contract does not mention being a mini-job. It states that I am an independent contractor and am responsible for all the insurances and taxes.

Does it count as a mini-job, as long as I do not earn more than 450€ per month? My employer does not forbid me from working on a side job, there are no issues on that side.

[Mini-job's definition from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_employment):

> Marginal employment (German: geringfügige Beschäftigung), also called
> a mini job or €450 job, is an employment relationship with a low
> absolute level of earnings or of short duration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Germany or "mini-jobs", but is this really a question specific for expats? If not, it'd likely be a better fit for the [Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question really needs some context. What is a 'mini-job'? Is that something specifically mentioned in German visa/immigration law? Could you provide a link?

Comment: @ouflak I edited the question

Comment: I think not, since that seems to be when you only have that job. Are you hoping to not have to pay taxes on the 450 ? You pay taxes on total income I believe (and in Germany even total global income, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @TomasBy yes thats kind of what I was hoping. There are different kinds of taxes and insurances in Germany, which are taken directly from the salary. To be exact, there's Solidarity Surcharge, salary Tax, Pension Insurance, Unemployment Insurance, Health Insurance, and Care Insurance. I think that I only have to pay taxes on the 'salary tax' with this extra job, and not on all those other taxes and social charges. But I'm not sure whether I'm right or not.